# Better version of draw9patch

Tags: android

I've been using draw9patch on android a bit lately and am getting frustrated about how bad of a program it is. I generally takes me 5 mintues per image to add the patches which seems excessive. Worse is that when I have multiple states for an image I have to do the exact same patches on 3 images or they look wrong, I would rather be able to just copy patches between images. I've tried using gimp to do the same thing but find it more difficult.

Has anyone found a better program to create 9 pngs or created their own?

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related.

Comment: I hate that when you zoom in the top place to put pixels gets covered up, its hard to paint in the pixels all the way zoomed out.  I've used photoshop as well but its not much easier.

Comment: I hate this tool after 10 usings. In addition to the most silly method of drawing lines pixel-by-pixel you must after clicking "Save 9-path" navigate to your target `/res/drawable` directory again and again to save the new file. Photoshop, Paint.NET etc. are not a solutions because there is no tool to see bad patches. Do anybody know an alternative program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What exactly are you doing? It shouldn't take more than 4 or 5 clicks to add patches. You're just adding single black pixels or lines of pixels on the outer frame.

Personally, I use Photoshop to do mine, but if you don't already have it, it's an expensive investment. GIMP or Paint.NET can easily do the same (technically, even MS Paint, but I wouldn't wish that program on anyone), and they're free.

EDIT: Somehow overlooked that you've already tried GIMP. Any new software is going to have some learning curve, especially if it contains more functionality. draw9patch is pretty much the bare minimum of functionality, so it's simple to use, but trust me when I say it would be worth your while to just improve your skills in GIMP or Paint.NET instead.

EDIT: Okay, just wanted to say I judged too quickly here. I've really only used the draw9patch tool for minor modifications, and testing my NinePatches I made in Photoshop. The process of drawing a line in d9p is an absolute pain in the ass. I see in your comment you said you've tried Photoshop. What you can actually do to make it easier is add guides (View > New Guide) at the pixel locations you want, then just use the pencil tool at a 1px brush size, click and hold at the start of the line, hold shift and then drag to the end of the line. Photoshop has an annoying bug, however (at least in my installation of CS2) of selecting the wrong pixel when zoomed in very close, so you may have to end up erasing a few stray pixels that end up past the guides. I would do your black border as a separate layer as well, to make things easier.

Comment: I find the problem is that I often want a line along an edge which means I have to go along pixel by pixel. Unless I'm missing something and there is a way to draw a line in draw9patch.

Comment: Just wanted to add some commentary now that I'm home and tried out the ninepatch tool again. I remembered it differently. >.>

Answer (score 0):

GIMP does not have a Line Tool, however if you pick the Pencil tool, then you can press Shift to make lines (well done GIMP, everyone should have been able to guess to press Shift, right?).

{[complete tutorial](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Straight_Line/)}

Comment: Eh, Shift's actually a pretty common shortcut for constraining drawing angles. Office does this, Adobe software does this, even MS Paint.

Comment: @kcoppock: if Shift is for constraining drawing angles, I'd be very happy. Instead the shift is necessary for drawing an unconstrained basic line. And even then, it's not just drag from here to there while pressing shift, it's click here, press shift, and then click there, and if you want to draw constrained line, you need to click, press shift, press ctrl, then click again, in that exact order (if you press ctrl then shift, you'll instead switch to eyedropper tool). All just for drawing a simple line.

Comment: If that's the case, then MS Paint has GIMP beat in usability, haha. I'm not a GIMP user myself (though I know people who swear by it), so I have no experience with it. That's insane if they don't even allow for shift-drag line drawing. :/

Comment: @kcoppock: Granted, GIMP was not designed for drawing (for that, Inkscape is used). GIMP is a tool for retouching and editing photos/images (on this edge it's a powerful tool).

Answer (score 0):

This is an older post, but there is a tool out now called [Better 9 Patch Tool](http://www.roundrect.kr/desktop/better-9-patch/) that makes drawing these a breeze. The whole thing is written in Java so it runs on pretty much everything and is Shareware, so you can try it before you buy it. And if you're unhappy with doing this in Photoshop or the draw9patch tool (as I was) this is a pretty good alternative.

Link is here:
http://www.roundrect.kr/desktop/better-9-patch/